# URL rewrites with php5-fpm on apache2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-fastcgi

i want to use URL rewrites with PHP5.6-FPM on Apache2.2.22 (Debian 7) but i wont work.
If i activate the URL rewrites via .htaccess file my server throws a 500 error (Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.)

```
[Mon Oct 12 01:56:09 2015] [error] [client 93.232.122.47] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: ***********
[Mon Oct 12 01:56:09 2015] [debug] core.c(3116): [client 93.232.122.47] r->uri = /php5.fcgi/index.php, referer: ***********
[Mon Oct 12 01:56:09 2015] [debug] core.c(3122): [client 93.232.122.47] redirected from r->uri = /index.php, referer: ***********
[Mon Oct 12 01:56:09 2015] [debug] core.c(3122): [client 93.232.122.47] redirected from r->uri = /php5.fcgi/index.php, referer: ***********
[Mon Oct 12 01:56:09 2015] [debug] core.c(3122): [client 93.232.122.47] redirected from r->uri = /index.php, referer: ***********
[Mon Oct 12 01:56:09 2015] [debug] core.c(3122): [client 93.232.122.47] redirected from r->uri = /php5.fcgi/index.php, referer: ***********
[Mon Oct 12 01:56:09 2015] [debug] core.c(3122): [client 93.232.122.47] redirected from r->uri = /index.php, referer: ***********
[Mon Oct 12 01:56:09 2015] [debug] core.c(3122): [client 93.232.122.47] redirected from r->uri = /php5.fcgi/index.php, referer: ***********
[Mon Oct 12 01:56:09 2015] [debug] core.c(3122): [client 93.232.122.47] redirected from r->uri = /index.php, referer: ***********
[Mon Oct 12 01:56:09 2015] [debug] core.c(3122): [client 93.232.122.47] redirected from r->uri = /php5.fcgi/index.php, referer: ***********
[Mon Oct 12 01:56:09 2015] [debug] core.c(3122): [client 93.232.122.47] redirected from r->uri = /index.php, referer: ***********
[Mon Oct 12 01:56:09 2015] [debug] core.c(3122): [client 93.232.122.47] redirected from r->uri = /intern/, referer: ***********
[Mon Oct 12 01:56:09 2015] [debug] mod_deflate.c(700): [client 93.232.122.47] Zlib: Compressed 637 to 391 : URL /php5.fcgi/index.php, referer: ***********
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   # Enable URL rewriting
   RewriteEngine Off

   # Store the current location in an environment variable CWD to use
   # mod_rewrite in .htaccess files without knowing the RewriteBase
   RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
   RewriteRule ^.*$ - [E=CWD:%2]

   # Rule for versioned static files, configured through:
   # - $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['versionNumberInFilename']
   # - $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['versionNumberInFilename']
   # IMPORTANT: This rule has to be the very first RewriteCond in order to work!
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(php|js|css|png|jpg|gif|gzip)$ $1.$3 [L]

   # Access block for folders
   RewriteRule _(?:recycler|temp)_/ - [F]
   RewriteRule fileadmin/templates/.*\.(?:txt|ts)$ - [F]
   RewriteRule typo3temp/logs/ - [F]
   RewriteRule ^(vendor|typo3_src) - [F]
   RewriteRule (?:typo3conf/ext|typo3/sysext|typo3/ext)/[^/]+/(?:Configuration|Resources/Private|Tests?)/ - [F]

   # Access block for files or folders starting with a dot
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
   RewriteRule (?:^|/)\. - [F]

   # Stop rewrite processing, if we are in the typo3/ directory or any other known directory
   # NOTE: Add your additional local storages here
   RewriteRule (?:typo3/|fileadmin/|typo3conf/|typo3temp/|uploads/|favicon\.ico) - [L]

   # If the file/symlink/directory does not exist => Redirect to index.php.
   # For httpd.conf, you need to prefix each '%{REQUEST_FILENAME}' with '%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}'.
   #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/fastcgiphp/*
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:CWD}index.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
   Action php5-fcgi /php5.fcgi
   Alias /php5-fcgi /var/www/php5-fcgi
   FastCgiExternalServer /var/www/php5.fcgi -socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

   DocumentRoot /var/www
   #<Directory />
   #       Options FollowSymLinks
   #       AllowOverride none
   #</Directory>
   <Directory /var/www/>
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
          AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes Options
          Order allow,deny
          allow from all
   </Directory>

   ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
   <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
          AllowOverride None
          Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
   </Directory>

   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

   # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
   # alert, emerg.
   LogLevel debug

   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this last `RewriteRule` line:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:CWD}index.php [QSA,L]
```

to this:

```
RewriteRule !index\.php index.php [NC,L]
```

and restest.

Comment: You are my hero! Thank you!